# jQuery - appended script executed after all page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, append

I'm currently working on a page that have one iframe and one script adding a menu bar.

The iframe have a script which is long to load, and the other script for the menu have to be add dynamically like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');

    var url = 'URL TO SCRIPT THAT ADD MENU BAR';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    jQuery("head").append(script);

});
```

After testing it seems that this code is executed but Chrome wait for the iframe to be completely loaded so the bar appears after few seconds when the iframe page has finished loading.

So is there a way to execute the script appended before the script in the iframe?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you could take that out of the DOM ready so it triggers instantly?

Comment: Already tried. Actually it execute the "jQuery("head").append(script);" lines but the script appended isn't executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<iframe onload='load_script()'></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
        function load_script (){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: URL,
                dataType: "script"
            });
        }
```

Comment: Does ajax changes a thing instead of appending the script directly? I do not see the goal of doing that ^^'

Comment: Nop, you can append, but I prefer doing this way, but what matters is the function onload of the iframe. :)

Comment: Finaly worked by making the src of the iframe change on the loading of the page. The load of the iframe would create infinite loop :)